# R: Melt and Dcast

Tags: r, melt, dcast

I have a dataset like this:

```
CASE_ID = c("C1","C1", "C2","C2", "C2", "C3", "C4") 
PERSON_ID = c(1,0,7,8,1,20,7) 
PERSON_DIVISION = c("Zone 1", "NA", "Zone 1", "Zone 3", "Zone 1", "Zone 5", "Zone 1") 
df <- data.frame(CASE_ID, PERSON_ID, PERSON_DIVISION)  
df
```

That results in:

```
CASE_ID PERSON_ID PERSON_DIVISION
1      C1         1          Zone 1
2      C1         0              NA
3      C2         7          Zone 1
4      C2         8          Zone 3
5      C2         1          Zone 1
6      C3        20          Zone 5
7      C4         7          Zone 1
```

And I want to transform it in:

```
CASE_ID P1_ID  P2_ID  P3_ID  P1_Division  P2_Division   P3_Division
1       1       0     NA        Zone 1      NA           NA
2       7       8     1         Zone 1      Zone 3      Zone 1
3       20      NA    NA        Zone 5      NA          NA
4       7       NA    NA        Zone 1      NA          NA
```

My approach so far has been to melt the data and laters Dcast:

```
e <- melt(df)

dcast(e, CASE_ID  ~ PERSON_DIVISION + variable)
```

But I am not getting the desired output, instead I am getting:

```
CASE_ID NA_PERSON_ID Zone 1_PERSON_ID Zone 3_PERSON_ID Zone 5_PERSON_ID
 1      C1            1                1                0                0
 2      C2            0                2                1                0
 3      C3            0                0                0                1
 4      C4            0                1                0                0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two issues here:

1. Your data is already in long format but you have *two* value columns. The recent versions of `data.table` support multiple value vars in `dcast()`.
2. You need unique row ids within each group. Otherwise, `dcast()` will try to aggregate duplicates (using `length()` by default which explains the output you've got).

Please, try

```
library(data.table)   # version 1.10.4 used here
# coerce to data.table, add unique row numbers for each group
setDT(df)[, rn := rowid(CASE_ID)]
# dcast with multiple value vars
dcast(df, CASE_ID ~ rn, value.var = list("PERSON_ID", "PERSON_DIVISION"))
#   CASE_ID PERSON_ID_1 PERSON_ID_2 PERSON_ID_3 PERSON_DIVISION_1 PERSON_DIVISION_2 PERSON_DIVISION_3
#1:      C1           1           0          NA            Zone 1                NA                NA
#2:      C2           7           8           1            Zone 1            Zone 3            Zone 1
#3:      C3          20          NA          NA            Zone 5                NA                NA
#4:      C4           7          NA          NA            Zone 1                NA                NA
```

This can be written more concisely as a one-liner:

```
dcast(setDT(df), CASE_ID ~ rowid(CASE_ID), value.var = list("PERSON_ID", "PERSON_DIVISION"))
```